# PowerShell : need to Compare the 2 csv, compare files first column of each and get the matching values 2nd column from 2nd file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have 2 csv file. 1st file have deviceName and 2nd file have deviceName and id as a header of the column.
I need to check if the first file deviceName is present in file first column deviceName and i need the output as the corresponding id value from 2nd file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself by opening a new question in case the referred duplicate answer doesn't satisfy your question. Note this is *not* a script factory (maybe you should try  [Chat-GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT) if you expect otherwise). You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the expected output but this works and filters out file 2 values based on file 1.

Adapt delimeter and encoding accordingly your need, mine being ";"

```
$file1 = Import-Csv -Path path_to_csv1 -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default
$file2 = Import-Csv -Path path_to_csv2 -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default

$file2 | Where-Object { $_.deviceName -in $file1.deviceName}
```

Comment: Did not get any output after i ran this code : $file1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\notinazure2.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default
$file2 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\devices_IntuneAllDevices.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default

$file2 | Where-Object { $_.deviceName -in $file1.deviceName}

Comment: Below are the more details regarding me request.

the file have only 1 column with name deviceName and Data of 1st file:

deviceName
abc
sdj
ifk

2nd file have 2 columns as deviceName and id and below is the Data of 2nd file:

deviceName ;               id
abc                   325493947
yjd                  907877698
ple                   077545689

and i want to check if 1st file's deviceName's are present in 2nd file's first column and get its corresponding id(if the deviceName matched) which is in 2nd column.
output:

id
325493947

Comment: Works fine with me as based on your description. As stated above this is not an out of the box script. Up to you to investigate and adapt.